# Can't read REST API with an XML response using Synapse Pipeline's Copy Activity

Tags: rest, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

Trying to read REST API endpoints through Synapse pipeline and sinking it in a JSON format. The API response is XML and the run ends up erroring out.

--------Error---------
{
"errorCode": "2200",
"message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=JsonInvalidDataFormat,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error occurred when deserializing source JSON file ''. Check if the data is in valid JSON object format.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException,Message=Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.,Source=Newtonsoft.Json,'",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "Copy REST API Data",
"details": []
}
--------Error---------

Do not want to go back and use existing C# script-based code which is currently run through SSIS packages.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using **Rest Connector**?

Comment: Try using HTTP connector

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repro this using Rest connector in ADF and got the same error. Rest connector supports only JSON file. Refer this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#supported-capabilities) on Supported capabilities of REST connector.

[image]

Instead use **HTTP connector** and select **XML dataset**. Below is the approach to do it.

- Select HTTP in linked service.
  [image]
- Enter Base URL and authentication type and then click create.
  [image]
- Create new dataset for HTTP linked service. Select HTTP and then continue.

[image]

- Select XML format and then select continue.
  [image]
- Give the linked service and relative url and then click OK.
  [image]
- Use this dataset as source dataset in copy activity. Once pipeline is run, data will be copied to sink.

Comment: Thanks a heap Aswin. I tried with HTTP linked service with XML format, and JSON sink. It worked like a charm.